# Dart:ffi - 'must be a subtype' for 'lookupFunction' issue for native code in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows, dart-ffi, psapi

`The type 'Uint32 Function(IntPtr, Pointer<Uint32>)' must be a subtype of 'int Function(IntPtr, Pointer<Uint32>)' for 'lookupFunction'.`

```
class Psapi {
  static final ffi.DynamicLibrary psapi = ffi.DynamicLibrary.open('psapi.dll');

  static int GetWindowThreadProcessId(
      ffi.IntPtr hwnd, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> lpdwProcessId) {
    return psapi.lookupFunction<ffi.Uint32 Function(ffi.IntPtr hwnd, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> lpdwProcessId),
        int Function(ffi.IntPtr hwnd, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> lpdwProcessId)>('GetWindowThreadProcessId')(
      hwnd,
      lpdwProcessId,
    );
  }
}
```

In this code `int Function(ffi.IntPtr hwnd, ffi.Pointer<ffi.Uint32> lpdwProcessId)` this part shows error and says `The type 'Uint32 Function(IntPtr, Pointer<Uint32>)' must be a subtype of 'int Function(IntPtr, Pointer<Uint32>)' for 'lookupFunction'`
Can someone explain where it gone wrong and what's the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got that answer on github https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/54298

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lookupFunction`'s second type argument represent the Dart function signature for the corresponding `Win32` function. IntPtr's Dart signature would be `int`. But implementing the code directly can cause error.